# Who authored the page and...?

Tags: discussion

I would love to be able to easily find an author/artist name in or appended to an article or page by that author-artist-mathematician. Where can I find that datum?

---

I initially wanted to know who did the great CGI image of the algebraic numbers in the complex plane. I finally searched long and hard enough to find his/her page here (the mathematica site). I also found several other great related graphics at the same page, but no name or names

---

The maths artist seems to be "DumpsterDoofus" and here's the page of initial interest: [Visualisation of the field of algebraic numbers in the complex plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115758/visualisation-of-the-field-of-algebraic-numbers-in-the-complex-plane/151230#151230) < thanks, but who is DD really? (so I can give him due credit after hopefully getting permission to use his maths graphics).

Comment: His [profile in flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/104348204@N05/) seems to have a contact button.